# How to use foreach or foreachBatch in PySpark to write to database?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I want to do Spark Structured Streaming (Spark 2.4.x) from a Kafka source to a MariaDB with Python (PySpark).

I want to use the streamed Spark dataframe and not the static nor Pandas dataframe.

It seems that one has to use `foreach` or `foreachBatch` since there are no possible database sinks for streamed dataframes according to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks.

Here is my try:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, DoubleType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
# configuration of target db
db_target_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database"
db_target_properties = {"user":"writer", "password":"1234"}
# schema
schema_simple = StructType([StructField("Signal", StringType()),StructField("Value", DoubleType())])

# create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("streamer").getOrCreate()

# create DataFrame representing the stream
df = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "mytopic") \
  .load() \
  .selectExpr("Timestamp", "cast (value as string) as json") \
  .select("Timestamp", F.from_json("json", schema_simple).alias('json_wrapper')) \
  .selectExpr("Timestamp", "json_wrapper.Signal", "json_wrapper.Value")
df.printSchema()
# Do some dummy processing
df2 = df.filter("Value < 11111111111")
print("df2: ", df2.isStreaming)

def process_row(row):
    # Process row
    row.write.jdbc(url=db_target_url, table="mytopic", mode="append", properties=db_target_properties)
    pass
query = df2.writeStream.foreach(process_row).start()
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: write

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the support of Jacek, I could fix my example:

```
def process_row(df, epoch_id):
    df2.write.jdbc(url=db_target_url, table="mytopic", mode="append", properties=db_target_properties)
    pass
query = df2.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_row).start()
```

You also must put the **epoch_id** into the function parameters. Otherwise you get errors in the spark log file that are not shown in the jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 13):

**tl;dr** Replace `foreach` with `foreachBatch`.

---

Quoting the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch):

> The `foreach` and `foreachBatch` operations allow you to apply arbitrary operations and writing logic on the output of a streaming query. They have slightly different use cases - while `foreach` allows custom write logic on every row, `foreachBatch` allows arbitrary operations and custom logic on the output of each micro-batch.

In other words, your `writeStream.foreach(process_row)` acts on a single row (of data) that has no `write.jdbc` available and hence the error.

Think of the row as a piece of data that you can save anywhere you want using any API you want.

If you really need support from Spark (and do use `write.jdbc`) you should actually use `foreachBatch`.

> while `foreach` allows custom write logic on every row, `foreachBatch` allows arbitrary operations and custom logic on the output of each micro-batch.

Comment: does `foreach` or `foreachBatch` slow down the application?

Comment: No further (micro)batches are going to be started until the current one has finished. So, be as quick in `foreach` and `foreachBatch` as possible.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski - is watermark supported when we use foreachbatch ?

Comment: @KaranAlang Please ask a separate question 

Answer (score 1):

```
#
here working code spark Structured Streaming  (3.2.1)
from kafka to postgres

   

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(stg).getOrCreate()                  
jdbcDF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<>") \
    .option("subscribe", "<>") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()



jdbcDF = jdbcDF.withColumn("value",col("value").cast(StringType()))

df = jdbcDF


def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    df.printSchema()
    df.show()
    df.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", stg) \
    .option("user", pg_username) \
    .option("password", pg_password) \
    .option("truncate", True) \
    .save()

writing_sink = df.writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime='12 seconds') \
    .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function) \
    .start()
    

writing_sink.awaitTermination()

spark.stop()
```

- need jar lib

commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar,
kafka-clients-3.2.1.jar,
postgresql-42.5.0.jar,
spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar,
spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.2.1.jar

Comment: Can you please elaborate where the variables `url`, `stg`, `pg_username`, `pg_password` inside the `foreach_batch_function()` are defined at?  I am asking because the parameters of this function is fixed with `(DataFrame, Long)`.  Thanks.