# How to write spark structure stream into mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Spark dataframe can be written into mongodb collection. Refer - https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/write-to-mongodb/

But when tried to write spark structure stream into mongodb collection, it is not working.

Can you please suggest any better option to achive this than using pymongo code in udf.

Comment: How do you know _"it is not working."_? Can you include the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is resolved using `foreachBatch` sink. PFB working sample code.

```py
def write_mongo_row(df, epoch_id):
    mongoURL = "mongodb://XX.XX.XX.XX:27017/test.collection"
    df.write.format("mongo").mode("append").option("uri",mongoURL).save()
    pass

query=csvDF.writeStream.foreachBatch(write_mongo_row).start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

got idea from [How to use foreach or foreachBatch in PySpark to write to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766638/how-to-use-foreach-or-foreachbatch-in-pyspark-to-write-to-database)

Comment: Is there another alternative, other than initializing the mongo connection each time the function is called?

Answer (score 2):

Sharing an alternative solution where config part is taken care at very beginning  rather than handling configs later in `save` method (to seperate configs from logic).

```
def save(message: DataFrame):
    message.write \
        .format("mongo") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("database", "db_name") \
        .option("collection", "collection_name") \
        .save()
    pass

spark: SparkSession = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1") \
    .master("local") \
    .getOrCreate()

df: DataFrame = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()

query: StreamingQuery = df\
    .writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(save) \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Support for Apache Structured Streaming was added recently in version 10 of the MongoDB Spark Connector.  See

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-mongodb-spark-connector

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-mongodb-spark-connector-version-10-1?

and

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/structured-streaming/