# StructuredStreaming - read from Strimzi Kafka on GKE, writing data into Mongo every 10 minutes

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have data in Kafka topic(data published every 10 mins) and i'm planning to read this data using Apache Spark Structured Stream(batch mode) and push it in MongoDB.

Pls note :
This will be scheduled using Composer/Airflow on GCP - which will create a Dataproc cluster, run the spark code, and then delete the cluster

Here is my current code :

```
# read from Kafka, extract json - and write to mongoDB 

df_reader = spark.readStream.format('kafka')\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers)\
    .option("kafka.security.protocol","SSL") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location",ssl_truststore_location) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password",ssl_truststore_password) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location)\
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password)\
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .option("kafka.group.id", consumerGroupId)\
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

df = df_reader.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
df_data = df.select(from_json(col('value'),schema).alias('data')).select("data.*").filter(col('customer')==database)

# write to Mongo
df_data.write\
    .format("mongo") \
    .option("uri", mongoConnUri) \
    .option("database", database) \
    .option("collection", collection) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

Since this is run as a batch query every 10 minutes, how do i ensure that duplicate records are not read, and pushed into MongoDB ?

When i use readStream - does read all the data in Kafka topic OR from the point it last read the data ?
How does df.read differ from df.readStream in this case ?

Pls note :
mongo datasource does not support streaming query, else i could have used the checkpoint to enable this ?

Pls advise what is the best way to achieve this ?

tia!

Comment: Kafka uses the offset tracker to make sure any consumer in the consumer group would start reading from where it last read from. Which version of spark are you using(or plan)?
Reference: 
https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/streaming-data-apache-spark-mongodb/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125482/how-to-write-spark-structure-stream-into-mongodb-collection

If you only moving data from kafka to mongo, you can look into kafka connectors as well.

Comment: @teedak8s - i'm using Spark 3.1.2 on GCP ... also, pls see my responses to the post from OneCricketeer for details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule the job to run every X minutes, you should use `spark.read.format("kafka")`, otherwise, it will start a long-running Spark Structured Streaming job, not a batch job.

Spark will track offsets either in Kafka, or with a `checkpointLocation`, which you'll want to configure.

Also - stuctured streaming writes [do work with Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/structured-streaming/#configuring-a-write-stream-to-mongodb).

As commented, [Kafka Connect](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/) might be more useful than scheduling anything, though, and you can use GKE or maybe Cloud-Run to start Kafka Connect worker containers, or create a cluster in GCE. This will run continuously, and you won't have to wait 10+ minutes (depending on Kafka consumer lag).

Comment: does the Spark use checkpoint location  in batch mode ? from what i know, checkpoint is used only for streaming jobs.  I'm using Airflow to create the Dataproc cluster, run the spark job, and then bring down the cluster.   In this scenario - the batch spark job will consume all data present in the kafka topic at every run(from what i understand & observed) .. with Structured Streaming using trigger(once=True), i can leverage the checkpoint used by StructuredStreaming .. .this is what i'm doing currently .. pls let me know your thoughts on this approach.

Comment: Also, @OneCricketeer - thnx, will check KafkaConnect as well, though i have some logic built in eg. each data is put into specific MongoDB based on the customer field in the data

Comment: Pls note - we get source syslog data every 10 mins .. so there is no need for me to keep reading/processing the data continously